# How to search online database with android app

Tags: android

Im writing an android app just to search my website and return results only,Ive been seeing API everywhere,Which kind of API should I use and how do I go about it?

Comment: R you talking about MYSQL database..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making a [RESTful web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services), call it in your app by executing a HTTPGet request in your AsyncTask and then process the JSON object that is returned.

1. The app calls the web service
2. The web service process the request by querying it's database
3. The service returns a result (preferably JSON)
4. The app process the result

Comment: Thanks,This has reduced my questions..But how or where can I get the tutorials,No luck searching online

Comment: You can check my GitHub repo - https://github.com/TheMedo ,
it has couple of web services. I'm using .NET framework with MSSQL database and I'm hosting the code on https://appharbor.com/

Comment: Is the Restful webservice a php thingy?